# Cart User Add A New Record Width ADO Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, cart

I use ado entity framework and add a new product to my cart but i can't set logged user. When i save entity so my application create a new record in User table. But i'm logged in already and i get my user object from session.

```
Product prod = db.Product.Where(t => t.ProductId == ProductId).FirstOrDefault();

Cart mycart = new Cart();
mycart.Product = prod;

//I can get user object from session. I'm logged in.
mycart.User = (User)Session["LoggedUser"]; //this line create a new row to User table. but i'm already logged in
mycart.Price = prod.Price;
mycart.SessionID = Session.SessionID;

db.Cart.Add(mycart);
db.SaveChanges();

/*** my cart class *//
public class Cart{

    [Key]
    public int CartId{get;set;}

    public virtual Product Product{get;set;}
    public virtual User User {get;set;}
    public int Quantity{get;set;}
    public string SessionID { get; set; }
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Why don't you insert a line of code  var usr = (User)Session["LoggedUser"]; above the myCart.User = ... line, put a break point on the next line and see exactly what usr variable holds after that line executes?

Comment: It's hold logged user's entity.